# In javascript, I not success to stop my loop with clearIntereval for setInterval

Tags: javascript, loops, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a countdown who will display a new piture every 5 secondes >> it approximatively work, but at the end of the array composed by 10 pictures, I am not able to stop countdown + stop to display picture with the clearInterval...

[image]

My script

```
<script>
      var myImage = document.getElementById ("mainImage");
      var imageArray = ["img/lunge.png", 
                        "img/plank.png", 
                        "img/push-up-and-rotation.png", 
                        "img/push-up.png", 
                        "img/side-plank-left.png", 
                        "img/side-plank-right.png", 
                        "img/squat.png", 
                        "img/step-up-onto-chair.png", 
                        "img/triceps-dip-on-chair.png", 
                        "img/wall-sit.png"]
      var imageIndex = 0;
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#submit').click(function () {
              $('.timer').circularCountDown()
              var inter = setInterval (changeImage, 5000);
              function changeImage () {
                  myImage.setAttribute ("src", imageArray [imageIndex]);
                  document.getElementById("circle").innerHTML = "";
                  imageIndex++;
                  if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
                      imageIndex =0;
                      }
                  $('.timer').circularCountDown()
                  }
              function stopinter () {
                  clearInterval (inter);
              }
          })
      })
  </script>
```

Any idea about how to do of improve my script ?

Thank you,

Olivier

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but I'm not seeing the `stopinter` function called anywhere...

Comment: On `stop` button click , call `stopinter()` function.

Comment: it should stop at the end the the array lenght... The stop button is an other way to stop but I not already writte my code for that...

Comment: Currnetly, my need is auto stop at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageIndex++;
if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
    stopinter();
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this answer. But finaly I find an other way. I will also try with your proposition ! ;-) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, I make it work with this solution :

```
$('.timer').circularCountDown()
                  for (;i==10;i++) {
                      clearInterval (inter);
                  }
```